# Can't install app on iOS 6.0.1 devices

Tags: iphone, ios6

I developing iphone app with xcode 4.5. I used TestFlight for ad hoc testing.
When upload build (.ipa) to TestFlight and get the installation link. i am able to install app on my iPad 5.0.1 using TestFlight installation link. But i tried to install app on iPhone 6.0.1 it gives me error message. "Won't install this app".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that XCode 4.5 doesn't support iOS 6.0.1. And hence your .ipa file isn't install in device with iOS 6.0.1. Solution to this is update your XCode to latest version which is 4.6. It'll solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution.

### The problem

The problem is the new OS does not contain proper info for old Xcode to load debug info, while this info can only be obtained by the latest Xcode.

### Solution

1. Install the latest Xcode(currently is Xcode 4.6, you can get it from Mac AppStore).
2. Connect your device while the new Xcode is open.(No matter what the order of open Xcode first or connect your device first)
3. Press **⌘ + Shift + 2** to open Xcode organizer, click the device icon if the organizer appears not in device tab
4. Wait under see your device with iOS 6.0.1(or even iOS 6.0, iOS 6.1.1) to **become green**
5. Now your new OS has enough debug information for old Xcode
6. Connect this device to your old Xcode 4.5. You should not be able to send app to device.

### Some disadvantages

1. You system will have 2 Xcode, if your old Xcode is also installed from Mac AppStore, you need to download the new Xcode from Developer center.
2. After you installed the new Xcode, you command line tools usually use the new Xcode as the default develop tools. Use `xcode-select` to switch to old Xcode's path.

Answer (score 0):

Please do check the udid id for that Device, or include the udid again and download the new profile and then archive with that profile. It just because of udid